# Can Rice Encoding be used for encoding fractional precision values?

Tags: encoding, compression, image-compression

I am trying to implement Rice/Golomb Encoding, and I executed the code given by the pseudo-code on Golomb Coding's Wikipedia page under the *Simple algorithm* section.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golomb_coding

According to pseudo-code the retrieval of values such as 0.34 etc, could not be possible.
Upon further learning, I found that for negative integers we need to make a non-negative integer mapping, and Rice/Golomb encoding is done on those non-negative integers.

The data that I need to encode is having real number values.

Can Rice/Golomb encoding be used on such values? If yes is there any implementation present that does that?

Comment: Real numbers in what range?

Comment: The array that I want to compress using the rice encoding is run length encoding of DCT of a grayscale image. So the values would have range from around -1000 to +1000.